# How to assign Foreign Key static in Django Post Model

Tags: python, django, post, static, return

I want to add static user my Foreign Key field because of guest's post, but i can't. I try to add first id like 1, "1", "id=1" but no result.
Can you help me pls?

Here is my model.py;

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

views.py;

```
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        if request.user == '':
            post.user = 1
            post.save()
        else:
            post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work. Rather than try to allocate an arbitrary integer, you should make the field `null=True` and not set it at all if the user is not authenticated.